# Problema al crear un fichero recopilatorio de hora e ip en php

Tags: php

Al acceder desde local a mi fichero php me aparece que la línea 10 está mal. El fichero registro.txt me guarda la entrada, pero no me da mi ip si accedo desde otro equipo no me aparece el fallo, ¿alguien sabe que puede ser?
Gracias

```
<?php
$dns=[
    '192.168.0.105'=>' Usuario1',
    '192.168.0.67'=>'  Usuario2',
    '192.168.0.99'=>'  Usuario3',
    '192.168.0.70'=>'  Usuario local',
    ];

$f=fopen('registro.txt','a');
fwrite($f, date('Y-m-d H:i:s').($dns[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]."\r\n"));
fclose($f);
?>
```

Mensaje de Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: ::1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\asir2_kevin\asir2.php
>   on line 10

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` te está devolviendo `::1` que es básicamente `localhost` o `127.0.0.1` pero en notación de IPv6, Te funciona si cambias el usuario local por:  `'::1' => 'Usuario local',` ?

Comment: Vale muchas gracias he cambiado el usuario local y ya no me da error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas tu solución seria agregando esta linea al codigo:

```
<?php
$dns=[
    '192.168.0.105'=>' Usuario1',
    '192.168.0.67'=>'  Usuario2',
    '192.168.0.99'=>'  Usuario3',
    '::1'=>'  Usuario local',
    ];

$f=fopen('registro.txt','a');
fwrite($f, date('Y-m-d H:i:s').($dns[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]."\r\n"));
fclose($f);
?>
```

El problema esta en que al acceder desde local al archivo php solo reconoce la ip local (127.0.0.1 o ::1). Agregando esta ip local se soluciona

Comment: Por favor, añade una explicación de "qué" es el problema y cómo tu solución lo arregla para futuros usuarios. Un saludo

Comment: El problema esta en que al acceder desde local al archivo php solo reconoce la ip local (127.0.0.1 o ::1). Agregando esta ip local se soluciona